# How to change the height of a dynamic div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div called `.spacer` which dynamically adds a height. I now want to change the height of the `.spacer` to add `40px` to the current dynamic height which when toggled, would add and remove 40px to the dynamic `.spacer` height.

```
<div class="spacer"></div> -- Shows an empty div which is then populated with a dynamic height.
```

```
 let spacer = $(".spacer");

 $(".profile-header-wrapper .search-icon").on("click", function(){
     fixedVideo.toggleClass("fixed-video-position");
     spacer.css("height", (spacer + 50) + "px").toggle();
});
```

Comment: You need to add a working snippet to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the height to `spacer + 50` and spacer is in fact a jQuery element, you should use `spacer.height() + 50`.

You snippet corrected:

```
 let spacer = $(".spacer");

 $(".profile-header-wrapper .search-icon").on("click", function(){
     fixedVideo.toggleClass("fixed-video-position");
     spacer.css("height", (spacer.height() + 50) + "px").toggle();
});
```

Now I'm assuming you use "toggle" because the element is hidden, on hidden elements `spacer.height()` may return empty and you'll have to fetch it from the CSS instead ( using something in the lines of `parseInt(spacer.css("height").replace("px",""))`).